# In Google Analytics, given I have a specific page, how do I track where the user went to next?

Tags: google-analytics, landing-page

Note: I'm an analytics "n00b".

I have a specific page on my website, say [**/users/register**].

**Where in Google Analytics do I go to see where visitors to that page went to next?**

I saw that, for that page, the was a column called "*Landing*", but the number there was lower than the number of visitors?

When I looked at that page under the *Landing Page report*, I saw that it looked to have the info I needed as it had an *Exit* value... however, I don't know what that means, and I don't understand why the Landing number is so much lower.

**Regardless I just want to see where visitors to that page went to next?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, what you want is *hidden* in Visitor Flow:

[image: Visitor Flow]

Go there, and find the page you want stats on where visitors went *next*. To do that, you need to click on that page and select "Explore traffic through here", which ultimately leads to another flow visualisation, but only includes traffic going to and from that page:

[image: Visitor Flow]

Answer (score 3):

In 2021, this is much easier. Go to Behavior - Site Content - All Pages and find the page you want. Then near the top left of the main tab, change to Navigation Summary. This shows the top 10 next pages.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would update this to include a 2018 answer and perhaps a bit more depth.

If you are like me and wanting to find where people are going from a specific page rather than the landing page, it's actually pretty easy!

Go to Behavior > Behavior Flow

[image: Google analytics sidebar Behavior flow option]

The default view here will show traffic from the landing page. To get a specific page, click the little settings cog beside the landing page as shown below

[image: Clicking the landing page settings]

You'll be able to "add an item". For my example, I wanted to see where people were going from the /category/ pages. So I used the "contains" /category/ to get all pages that have /category/ in the url.

Comment: This doesn't work for any pages except the landing page. Not sure why you say otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, in Google Analytics 4 (GA4) go to the Explore menu on the far left side menu:

[image]

On the explorations page click the "Path Exploration" template

[image]

On the page that appears, click the `STEP +1` drop down

[image]

Change the drop down to "Page title and screen name"

[image]

This should show a list of pages flowing from session_start. Click on any one of those pages to see the next page users went to.  Click on the page again to collapse the view.  Or click on one of the next pages to explore deeper on the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Landing Page report, now in this report at the top you should see two tabs

1. Explorer (which is selected by default)
2. Entrance Paths

You probably want to see the Entrance Paths.

Comment: also no, this shows where the visitors are coming from, not what the question original asked for ("Where in Google Analytics do I go to see where visitors to that page went to next?")...

Comment: do check this, the landing page report says "User started at this landing page:" (here you select your page, in this questiion's case its /user/register). Then there is a table beneath it which says "then viewed these pages:" ... so you should be able to see where visitors to that page went to next.

Comment: @DKOATED, have I misinterpreted this report?

Answer (score 0):

Under the "Content" menu on the left there is "In-Page Analytics".

This will show you where people clicked next for any given page.

Comment: no, this shows the accumulated statistics of clicks on any given link on that page.

Comment: Isn't that just another way of showing where they went to next? The question was "where visitors to that page went to next", this answer is a valid way to see what % of users are clicking link a or link b on that page. Vistors Flow is also another solution to the quesiton.